# Is there an alternative to synchronous xhr, which provides the feature of queuing the native handling of user input?

Tags: javascript, ajax, input, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

For nearly a decade I've been seeing warnings that the use of synchronous XHR (XMLHttpRequest) has been deprecated and even proposals to start throwing errors when they are made. I understand why people don't like them (they frequently lead to poor UX [User Experience]) and I agree that the vast majority of requests should be asynchronous, but as far as I can tell, they provide a useful UX feature that none of the proposed alternatives provide: they queue the user's input.

If I use an interface frequently and I know what to expect, I do not wait for visual cues to proceed with input e.g. if I'm using Windows and I want to open Chrome I will type `[WindowsKey]Chr[Enter]`. I don't wait for the start menu to appear, because I know that all of my input will be queued and played out.

I find this behaviour across all the OSs (operating systems) and UIs (user interfaces) I interact with and yet it seems to be missing in any of the web-based UIs I use. I fire up a new email in Thunderbird and start typing without problem, but if I do the same in Gmail I find that the first couple of characters of the email address are missing, because the dialog hadn't opened by the time I started typing. This would appear to be bad UX caused by asynchronous input handling.

The prevalence of this problem doesn't make me hopeful, but is there any recommended mechanism for dealing with this?

The two I can think of aren't really plausible outside of a limited set of use cases:

1. Move everything onto the client. This essentially means avoiding requests altogether, by moving all the logic for UI changes to the client, so they can be performed synchronously.
2. Implement a javascript event queue and attempt to reimplement all of the native behaviour of user input. I think this might painful, but doable for the use cases I gave, but a nightmare if I have to start considering, for example, OS specific keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You do bring up a pretty good point. The "missed" keystrokes and other events that are dropped as the content is not there can be annoying. I'm a power user for most applications and try to use shortcuts whenever possible - I know how immensely annoying it can be if you have to wait for a window/menu to be *visible* before issuing a command when you know you just need to press a sequence of keys to get where you want. That is rarer in websites, though. I guess there are alternatives but not very pretty ones: re-implement this functionality. Fire an async event and maybe try to store all

Comment: events that come in from the user, then replay them after the request comes back. This could be weird, though, especially if a request takes longer. And gets more complex you want to allow *some* events while waiting - like the user clicking somewhere while waiting. The complexity could be somewhat reduced if you throw up a "loading screen" and disallow interaction until request comes back. But it's also not perfect. Ideally, you want to be able to act on an interaction *now* even if you wait for a request. That is not always possible, as you might need to fetch data before you know what to

Comment: do. In some situations, you might try pre-loading the data (or what might be likely data) to smooth out user interaction. So, page loads up, it's ready and you silently do a background request for data that is not needed *now* but would be if the user opens up some menu. For the sake of example, let's say a button opens up a grid with data and some filters - both the filters and the data rely on the state of the screen before the button is pressed. So, you can't pre-fetch the data, as it might be costly, but you can fetch *likely* filter values, so user presses the button and you can show a

Comment: screen with some filters and then just wait for the data. When filters + data comes back, silently replace the filters you have with the actual values, if there is discrepancy. But it can be hard to pull off well in a lot of situations. It can also make the client very chatty with the server. Some local caching might help and you might need to make sure the design is *consistent* in such a way that you can cache a lot of similar stuff.